# How to make a freehand polyline option from drawing toolbar enabled throughout in arcmap

Tags: arcobjects

Following code selects freehand polyline as default draw tool on first go:

```
     final ICommandBars commandBars = app.getDocument().getCommandBars();
     final UID windowId = new UID();
     windowId.setValue("{57E77868-D015-11D2-9F31-00C04F6BC8DD}");
     final ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.find(windowId, false, false);
     app.setCurrentToolByRef(commandItem);
```

But once we finish with drawing first element, it goes back to its original settings i.e. it starts showing 'Polygon' as default draw option.

Is there a way to set drawing tool to freehand polyline option throughout application execution in Arc map

Regards,
Viji

Comment: it depends on your application. are you aware of geojson.io? it might be easier to draw there and import later.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that there is an **onDrawingCompleted** event to set your freehand back whenever ArcMap changes it. So you either can activate a timer that checks for the current tool and sets it back or create a dedicated thread to verify and set the current tool to freehand.

The following code is rewritten in VB.NET

```
Public Sub setFreeHand()

Dim sFreeHandID As String
sFreeHandID = "{57E77868-D015-11D2-9F31-00C04F6BC8DD}"

If Not Application.CurrentTool Is Nothing Then
     'if the tool is active exit.
    If Application.CurrentTool.ID = sFreeHandID Then Exit Sub
End If

 Dim commandBars As ICommandBars

 commandBars = Application.Document.commandBars

  Dim windowId As UID
  windowId = New UID
  windowId.Value = sFreeHandID

  Dim ci As ICommandItem

  ci = commandBars.Find(windowId, False, False)
  Application.CurrentTool = ci


End Sub
```

Keep a timer of 500 ms to check

```
Public Timer_Sub

setFreeHand()

End Sub
```

You can then control the timer by switching it off and on. This is the easiest way, However, not the cleanest.